# Why does Javascript treat days and months differently?

Tags: javascript, date-format

I've noticed that in JavaScript, when creating a `Date`, months are zero based, and days aren't.

For example:

```
var foo = new Date(2012, 1, 1)
```

produces February 1st 2012

Why is this?

Comment: `months = ['Jan', 'Feb',..., 'Nov', 'Dec']; month = months[date.getMonth()];`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Most likely the idea is, that the months are thought of as an index into an array of month names, while days are simply "counted".

Comment: That does make sense the more I think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Where this makes sense from an answer stand point, it's bat crap crazy to think this logic has been around for how long now and i've never questioned it before.

Comment: @rlemon The fact that you've never questioned that logic before only proves that it makes sense :)

Comment: FWIW, I *never* thought it made much sense. Processing dates in JavaScript was always something that made me shudder, because I'd usually forget things like this until I started debugging strange results.

Comment: FWIW, I am not a front end developer and don't often have to deal with dates in Javascript aside from the occasional `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: When it comes to Javascript, "this is why they did it" and "this makes a good sense" are two things you rarely hear together.

Comment: @rlemon: "bat crap crazy"? Maybe. I know for sure that I've never heard anyone say that these 0-based month values are a good idea, and I never expect to hear anyone say it either.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Finding a better way to process dates is why Jon Skeet created [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) and [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).  Also, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479) interesting.

Answer (score 15):

It may also be that Javascript dates were meant to mimic java dates. Java has similarly used a zero based month since the beginning.

[JDK API v1.0.2 : Date.getMonth()](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.util.Date.html#getMonth%28%29)

Comment: And the java spec mirrors the C tm structure.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar

Comment: That's not to say that the Java Date API is a terribly good example of good design ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Danny Kirchmeier's answer above, as [this article](https://allthingssmitty.com/2016/12/21/zero-based-date-christmas-and-emoji/) claims, here's the reason as explained by Brendan Eich, the creator of Javascript:

[image: Brendan Eich on Twitter explaining why month is zero-based, and day is 1-based in Javascript]

For reasons I'm not aware of, that Tweet seems to no longer exist, at least not for me (not a Twitter user).

Comment: Nice find! Do you think you could add the content of the tweet to your message in case the image is deleted?

Comment: I screenshotted the image and uploaded it on SE, so it shouldn't ever get deleted.

Comment: @connexo Famous last words! I hope you're right. :)

Comment: This legacy originates with [Taligent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taligent).  Sun licensed their Calendar implementation from IBM.  Fun fact: it supports 13 months so 12 is a valid month called 'Undecimber'.